# gunicorn error (No module called server) on flask app deployed on cloud foundry via IBM cloud

Tags: flask, ibm-cloud, gunicorn, cloud-foundry, continuous-deployment

I have a basic flask application i want to deploy on cloud foundry on IBM cloud. I have successfully deployed this app on Heroku with Procfile and requirements.txt and all provided. now i am trying to host same on IBM cloud as a way of being familiar with the solution But the build stage fails with this error.

ImportError: No module named server.

How do i debug this?

## gunicorn file

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

## manifest file

```
---
applications:
- instances: 1
  timeout: 180
  name: "Squad twin"
  buildpack: python_buildpack
  command: python manage.py start 0.0.0.0:$PORT
  memory: 128M
  domain: not-used.net
  host: not-used
  env:
    FLASK_APP : server
    FLASK_DEBUG : false
```

Error Output

```
2019-09-19T22:08:11.36+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.87+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [103] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.87+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [103] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (103) 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.87+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [103] [INFO] Using worker: sync 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.88+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [106] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 106 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [106] [ERROR] Exception in worker process 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Traceback (most recent call last): 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR worker.init_process() 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR self.load_wsgi() 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR self.callable = self.load() 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR return self.load_wsgiapp() 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR import(module) 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server' 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.93+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [106] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 106) 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.96+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [103] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
2019-09-19T22:08:13.96+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR [
2019-09-19 21:08:13 +0000] [103] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot. 
2019-09-19T22:08:14.04+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 0 
2019-09-19T22:08:14.04+0100 [CELL/SSHD/0] OUT Exit status 0 >
```

I have tried using `flask run` and `python3 app.py` on the Procfile to no avail. I have also added a `manage.py`, `manifest.yml`, `runtime.txt` and even `setup.py` files using the IBM cloud getting started guide but the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `command` on `manifest.yml` is overriding the one on the Procfile.

Change the `command` on your `manifest.yml` to:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT app:app`